# Better JavaScript Organisation and Execution The Unobtrusive Way - Self-Executing Anonymous Func

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-javascript, module-pattern

I'm slowly getting a better understanding of JavaScript but I'm stuck on how best to tackle this particular organization/execution scenario.

I come from a C# background and am used to working with namespaces so I've been reading up on how to achieve this with JavaScript.  I've taken what was already starting to become a large JavaScript file and split it out into more logical parts.

I've decided on a single file per page for page specific JavaScript with anything common to two or more pages, like reusable utility functions, in another namespace and file.

This makes sense to me at the moment and seems to be a popular choice, at least during the development process.  I'm going to use a bundling tool to combine these disparate files for deployment to production anyway so anything that makes development more logical and easier to find code the better.

As a result of my inexperience in dealing with lots of custom JavaScript I had a function defined in the common JavaScript file like this:

**common.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var historyUrl = '/history/GetHistory/';
    $.getJSON(historyUrl, null, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, d) {
            $('#history-list').append('<li>' + d.Text + '</li>');
        });
    });
});
```

This is obviously far from ideal as it is specific to a single page in the application but was being executed on every page request which is utterly pointless and insanely inefficient if not outright stupid.  So that led me to start reading up on namespaces first.

After a bit of a read I have now moved this to a page specific file and re-written it like this:

**Moved from common.js to historyPage.js**

```
(function(historyPage, $, undefined) {

    historyPage.GetHistory = function () {
        var historyUrl = '/history/GetHistory/';
        $.getJSON(historyUrl, null, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, d) {
                $('#history-list').append('<li>' + d.Text + '</li>');
            });
        });
    };
    }( window.historyPage = window.historyPage || {}, jQuery ));
```

I found this pattern on the [jQuery Enterprise page](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/).  I'm not going to pretend to fully understand it yet but it seems to be a very popular and the most flexible way of organizing and executing JavaScript with various different scopes whist keeping things out of the global scope.

However what I'm now struggling with is how to properly make use of this pattern from an execution point of view.  I'm also trying to keep any JavaScript out of my HTML Razor views and work in an unobtrusive way.

So how would I now call the `historyPage.GetHistory` function only when it should actually execute ie: only when a user navigates to the History page on the web site and the results of the function are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code I have detailed above in the question I have gotten it working by doing the following:

**In _Layout.cshtml**

```
    @if (IsSectionDefined("History"))
    {
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
            @RenderSection("History", required: false)
        });
      </script>
    }
```

**In History.cshtml**

```
@section History
{
  historyPage.GetHistory();
}
```

The code is executing as required only when the user requests the History page on the web site.  Although the comment from @Dagg Nabbit above has thrown me a curve ball in that I thought I was on the right track ... Hmm ...

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code, it would seem that the easiest test would be to check if the page you are on contains an element with an `id` of `history-list`.  Something like this:

```
var $histList = $('#history-list');

if($histList.length > 0){
    // EXECUTE THE CODE
}
```

Though if it really only ever needs to run on one given page, maybe it's just not a good candidate for a shared javascript file.

Comment: It's not in a shared file it's in the historyPage.js file that contains only code for the history page.  Is there a better way to encapsulate code for specific pages?

Comment: If this script only needs to run on one page, why do you need to "namespace" it in the first place? just write `function getHistory() { ... }` once and only include it on that page. If you already have a global "namespace" object, then use `myNS.getHistory = function() { ... };` -- there's really no reason for that messy IIFE here, and it sounds like you know for certain whether `historyPage` exists, so there should be no need for `window.historyPage = window.historyPage || {}` (and there's no need for `undefined`, since you're not using it; not that there *ever* is, because of `void`).

Comment: I'm new to working this intensely with potentially lots of JavaScript.  I'm trying to navigate through what appears to be very muddy waters with LOTS of differing opinions and methodologies.  I'm confused by your comment to be honest.  Like I said I'm not pretending to fully understand it yet.  Bearing in mind I'm also trying to do things unobtrusively I'm not sure how or where I would just write `function getHistory()`  As far as I'm concerned I have only written the function once, there is no duplicated code anywhere.  Sorry if I'm still being stupid.

Comment: @Jammer If it's already only included just on that page then I'm not sure what your actual question is.  In your question above you asked how to run it only "when a user navigates to the History page".  But it sounds like that isn't an issue.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I found that technique after posting the original question. I think I'm going to roll with that technique for now and as I gain a better understanding I'll be in a better position to reassess later on.  Thanks for the help.